# Jquery Datatables does not populate with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, electron

I am trying to build a web app with electron and I'm using Jquery datatables to populate data.
The problem is that I am facing is that the table does not load my data from data=[] array

```
var data=[];

$(document).ready(function () {

    var sql="select Name,IMEI,Price,Quantity,Memory,Color from products";
    connection.query(sql,function (err,rows) {
        if (err) {alert("Error")};
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            // console.log(Object.values(rows[i]))
            data.push(Object.values(rows[i]))
        }
    })

    console.log(data)

    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        data:data,
        columns:[
            {"data":"Name",title:"Name"},
            {title:"IMEI"},
            {title:"Price"},
            {title:"Quantity"},
            {title:"Memory"},
            {title:"Color"}
        ]
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) function to do what you want

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    var sql="select Name,IMEI,Price,Quantity,Memory,Color from products";
    connection.query(sql,function (err,rows) {

        if (err) {alert("Error")};

        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            table.row.add( {
                "Name":    Object.values(rows[i].Name),
                "IMEI":    Object.values(rows[i].IMEI),
                "Price":   Object.values(rows[i].Price),
                "Quantity":Object.values(rows[i].Quantity),
                "Memory":  Object.values(rows[i].Memory),
                "Color":   Object.values(rows[i].Color)
            } ).draw();
        }
    })
})
```